# Sorting Content easily - wish to avoid a "weight" integer

Tags: views, nodes

As the title describes, I want to create a mechanism with which a bunch of Content Types can be sorted 'easily' so they can be presented with a View according to that sorting.

Adding an Integer that would act as 'weight' should work but can end up being confusing if the number of nodes get's too high.

Ideally some sort of 'tablesorting' would be sweet.

Is there a way to accomplish such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Potential dup of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10632/sort-by-content-types-in-a-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "[Comparison of Node Ordering Modules](http://drupal.org/node/398508)".

I have tested most of these modules and decided to go with the [Weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight) module because it was easier to implement and slightly faster then all the other module because it does not add any table joins to your queries since it is re-using the node's sticky field. It includes a very easy to setup Views plugin for drag-n-drop sorting. The Weight module is designed to 'sort nodes', while DraggableViews is designed to 'sort anything'.

Comment: Of what i can see, Weight 1.x (stable) only adds a counter in the nodes themselves. While it does what it should, it doesn't offer the ease of use that i'd like to offer the site's admins *ideally*, a tabledrag sort-of thing.

Comment: In D6 it includes a 'Weight Changer' display. It is safe to assume that this feature was upgraded, but maybe reworked, for D7.

Answer (score 1):

[DraggableViews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) allows you to create any list based on a View, and then renders Drupals regular drag-handles system over that. My experience with D6 is good, when I last tried it in D7 it was a bit buggy, though that should work out soon enough if not already.

Comment: Yeah, a friend suggested draggableviews too but i am using views 3.x and not only is it in .dev state for D7, but it's also for views 2.x :(

Comment: Where does it say it's only for Views 2? By reading the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/724990) it seems like this is just not true.

Comment: 7.x-2.x-dev tar.gz (13.51 KB) | zip (17.48 KB)  2012-Jan-19 Notes

Comment: The version number of the draggableviews module has nothing to do with the Views version. In fact, if you look in the [draggableviews.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/draggableviews.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/draggableviews.module) file, the very first function they implement is hook_views_api, which clearly declares version 3 support.

Answer (score 0):

My old-web-style solution is to add the weight handly by editing the machine name of the content type (1_nodetypetosortfirst, 2_nodetypetosortsecond, etc.) and then sorting by content types (asc).

That's the easiest solution I found.

But better think twice the order (and validate it) because if you need to change later the machine name, it might be painful.

Oh yep, and I forget : group the result by the field content type if you want to have something like :
content type 1
- result
- result
- result
/ content type 2
- result
- result
...